# How to toggle report backup without running karate-junit5 in parallel

Tags: java, testing, karate, web-api-testing

I've noticed that if I execute parallel tests with junit5 karate would backup reports by default:

```
//have report backup
@Test
    void runParallel() {
        Results results = Karate.run(String.join(File.separator,"classpath:steps")).tags("@Read")
                .reportDir(KARATE_REPORT_DIR)
                .outputJunitXml(true)
                .parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
```

But not the same when running a single test with karate-junit5 interface, even with backupReportDir(true)

```
// no report backup
    @Karate.Test
    Karate run(){
        return Karate.run("classpath:steps").tags("@Read")
                .backupReportDir(true)
                .reportDir(KARATE_REPORT_DIR)
                .outputJunitXml(true);
    }
```

Is it designed intentional or an issue?

my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```